# Как убрать программу в трей без отображения в панели задач

Tags: python, qt

ОС: Windows7
Python: 3.3
PyQt: 4

Как можно программу полностью спрятать в трей, чтобы не висела иконка в панели задач, т.к. мини-программа будет в фоне, и нужно чтобы не сильно мешала.

p.s. + есть такая проблема, что иконка не отображается в трее. Гуглил, но все в основном 2007 года, и толком, что такая трабла и у линухи бывает не нашел. Есть у кого-то информация по этому поводу?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

На Qt/C++ я использовал **this->hide()** чтобы убрать окно с панели задач и **this->show()** чтобы вернуть на панель задач.

А для добавления трея

```
//Создаем Action'ы для меню
QAction quitAction = new QAction(tr("&Quit"), this);
connect(quitAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), qApp, SLOT(quit()));

//Создаем меню и добавляем Action в него
QMenu trayIconMenu = new QMenu(this);
trayIconMenu->addAction(quitAction);

//Загружаем иконку
QIcon icon;
icon.addFile(QString::fromUtf8(":/image.ico"), QSize(), QIcon::Normal, QIcon::Off);

//Создаем трей
QSystemTrayIcon trayIcon = new QSystemTrayIcon(this);
trayIcon->setContextMenu(trayIconMenu);
trayIcon->setIcon(icon);
trayIcon->setToolTip(tr("Текст в трее"));
trayIcon->show();
```

Извиняюсь что не на Python, но думаю, что на нем будет примерно так же.

Comment: Спасибо. Не сразу понял правда, что при создании дочернего окна надо родителя show-тить :))
С иконкой я разобрался. На Windows надо было без :/file.png писать, а просто file.png

Comment: :/file.png -- это если 'file.png' в ресурсах приложения. "просто file.png" -- это если файл в одном каталоге с приложением. Это не зависит от ОС ( вроде как ).

Comment: Спасибо. Буду знать

Answer (score 1):

Скрыть по нажатию на крестик

```
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        if self.check_box.isChecked():
            event.ignore()
            self.hide()
            self.tray_icon.showMessage(
                "Tray Program",
                "Application was minimized to Tray",
                QSystemTrayIcon.Information,
                2000
            )
```

Полный код самого простого примера

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication, QMainWindow,
    QLabel, QGridLayout, QWidget,
    QCheckBox, QSystemTrayIcon,
    QSpacerItem, QSizePolicy, QMenu, QAction, QStyle, qApp)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    """
         Сheckbox and system tray icons.
         Will initialize in the constructor.
    """
    check_box = None
    tray_icon = None

    # Override the class constructor
    def __init__(self):
        # Be sure to call the super class method
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(480, 80))             # Set sizes
        self.setWindowTitle("System Tray Application")  # Set a title
        # Create a central widget
        central_widget = QWidget(self)
        # Set the central widget
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        grid_layout = QGridLayout(self)         # Create a QGridLayout
        # Set the layout into the central widget
        central_widget.setLayout(grid_layout)
        grid_layout.addWidget(
            QLabel("Application, which can minimize to Tray", self), 0, 0)

        # Add a checkbox, which will depend on the behavior of the program when the window is closed
        self.check_box = QCheckBox('Minimize to Tray')
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.check_box, 1, 0)
        grid_layout.addItem(QSpacerItem(
            0, 0, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding), 2, 0)

        # Init QSystemTrayIcon
        self.tray_icon = QSystemTrayIcon(self)
        self.tray_icon.setIcon(
            self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_ComputerIcon))

        '''
            Define and add steps to work with the system tray icon
            show - show window
            hide - hide window
            exit - exit from application
        '''
        show_action = QAction("Show", self)
        quit_action = QAction("Exit", self)
        hide_action = QAction("Hide", self)
        show_action.triggered.connect(self.show)
        hide_action.triggered.connect(self.hide)
        quit_action.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)
        tray_menu = QMenu()
        tray_menu.addAction(show_action)
        tray_menu.addAction(hide_action)
        tray_menu.addAction(quit_action)
        self.tray_icon.setContextMenu(tray_menu)
        self.tray_icon.show()

    # Override closeEvent, to intercept the window closing event
    # The window will be closed only if there is no check mark in the check box
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        if self.check_box.isChecked():
            event.ignore()
            self.hide()
            self.tray_icon.showMessage(
                "Tray Program",
                "Application was minimized to Tray",
                QSystemTrayIcon.Information,
                2000
            )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[Источник](https://gitpress.io/u/1155/pyqt-example-MinimizeToTray)